# YouTube Data API receiving subscription feed

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I have two questions concerning the YouTube Data API:
First of all, how do I receive the user's subscription feed (https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions).
Secondly, when I set the parameter "publishedAfter" to e.g. 2016-09-18, earlier published videos are returned, too.

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me tell you your first question answer. Actually you cannot get subscription feed directly using api you can get a user subscription list by using

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&maxResults=50&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Then use the channelID to get its recent videos by the this xml feed.

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id={channelID}
```

But you need to make auth of that user to get his subscriptions feed. You can do it easily by youtube api sample script. There are some example to get access token and then use curl to get his feed.

Now for your second question.

I don't think you can get older feed from that channel. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you, I've already thought about that, but the Thing is, if I want to display a "subscription feed" I will have to get the channel list then load all channels' videos and the sort it by time. I don't think that this is very performant...

Comment: yes, you are right, but we are not maker of api, If you like this answer. please accept this answer.

Comment: I love this. It doesn't cost quota. I have more than 200 channels I follow. But this method lacks control such as maxResults seems fixed at 15 and there is no pagination to load more, it seems.